# Properties of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If $p_n$denotes the $n^\text{th}$ prime then the sum $\displaystyle\frac{1}{p_1}+\frac{1}{p_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p_n}$ is never an integer. Prove or disprove.

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you do some basic algebra yet on these terms to get them into one fraction?

Comment: Hm. Perhaps use the already-proven fact that the $n$th harmonic number is never an integer after $H_1$?

Comment: @Nilknarf No, *much* simpler! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number Theory Prime Reciprocals never an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450476/number-theory-prime-reciprocals-never-an-integer)

Answer (score 3):

$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{p_1}+\frac{1}{p_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p_n} = \frac{p_2p_3\cdots p_n+p_1p_3\cdots p_n+\cdots+p_1p_2\cdots p_{n-1}}{p_1p_2p_3\cdots p_n}$$

Note that $p_1=2$ is the only even prime number. So, the denominator is even, while all terms in the numerator are even, except for $p_2p_3\cdots p_n$, which is odd, and thus the numerator is odd.

So, the equation is always odd divided by even (also for the edge case $n=1$), and thus never an integer

Comment: okk, but if we re-frame the problem by taking only odd primes will we have a counter eg.

Comment: @MANMAID Good question. Indeed, we could ask: are there *any* prime numbers such that their reciprocals add up to an integer?  To that, I don't know the answer .. I just know you can't include $2$ :)

Comment: it is just (the value you get $- 1/2$).